# how to save value of input into a variable?

Tags: javascript

So I want to save input data into a variable and see if it fill the requirement. But what happens here is when I run the program and the name is more than 6 letters(which should be) I still get the error that the name should contain 6 letters. What am I doing wrong here?

```
let oGameData = {};


var nick1 = document.getElementById('nick1').value;
var nick2 = document.getElementById('nick2').value;

oGameData.nickNamePlayerOne = nick1;
oGameData.nickNamePlayerTwo = nick2;


function validatform(e){
const message = [];

if(oGameData.nickNamePlayerOne.length < 6 || oGameData.nickNamePlayerTwo.length < 6){
    message.push("your name must be more then 6 letters!!");
    console.log(message);
}


if(message.length > 0){
    e.preventDefault();
    errormasg.innerText = message.join(", ");
    let np = document.createElement("p");
    np.setAttribute("class", "errorMsg");
    errormasg.appendChild(np);
}
if(message.length == 0){
    initiateGame();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're saving the value into a variable **when the script first runs** and not when the `validatform` function is called **after the user has changed the value** by typing into the field.

Move the code which reads the `value` inside the function.

Comment: I tried putting value code into validate function but the if conditions don't work. I mean now even if the player name is less then 6 letters it starts the game and user doesn't get an error.